# How can I put a rails app and a wordpress blog on the same domain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, heroku

I have a rails 4 app that's hosted on Heroku. Let's say its domain is www.example.com.

I would like to set up a wordpress blog that's hosted elsewhere. I would like the blog to live at www.example.com/blog.

That is, I want to use a subdirectory instead of a subdomain. This is for SEO purposes.

Could you please provide advice on how I can implement this?

UPDATE: This is a new site, and the blog isn't set up yet. So there are not any incoming links to worry about breaking.

UPDATE #2: I tried using rack-reverse-proxy on heroku. The /blog/ pages were rendering fine. However, I would actually get redirected to blog.example.com/blog/ instead of keeping the displayed url www.example.com/blog/. I used the same code in the rack-reverse-proxy README. However, I can't find any evidence of anyone having done this successfully with rails 4. I moved the server from heroku to EC2 and now I'm going to try some more stuff.

Answer (score 0):

301 redirect requests for /blog to blog.example.com and setup a DNS entry for the blog subdomain.

Web bots/crawlers will update their indexes with a 301

You could also try something like https://github.com/jaswope/rack-reverse-proxy but judging by the nature of the question itself, that might be out of the scope of knowledge

Comment: Thanks for your help. Looking at the readme for rack-reverse-proxy, though, it says "it is not meant for production systems." This is a production app, so I'm scared by that disclaimer. Is there an alternative that should be used in production?

Comment: What you should do is setup the blog on a subdomain and do a 301 redirect from your rails app. That is the "best" way to do it

Comment: I would prefer to use a subdirectory rather than a subdomain so that any links I build give authority to the main site. Is there a good/clean way to do this with heroku? Or should I switch to EC2?

Comment: THere is no "good/clean way" to do it on Heroku no other than reverse proxy